# What was Dolgan's quote that sums up all stereotypical Dwarves?

Tags: raymond-e-feist, riftwar-cycle

In the first book of the Riftwar Cycle, Magician, the Dwarven leader Dolgan said something along the lines of that his three favorite things to do is spending time with his family (or perhaps just his wife), having a drink with his friends and being in a good fight: very stereotypical Dwarven stuff. But for the love of me I can't find the exact wording of what he said. Does anyone know where to find this quote, and what its exact wording was?

Comment: Wasn't able to find any sources of quotes from the book itself, so it seems only by rereading them will you get your answer. Perhaps someone has an e-book version and can search it faster than the paperback copy I have. I do love this book, and will happily read it again and keep an eye out for this quote for you. So if no one answers this for you in the next few weeks, I'll check back in.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero - Weeks? You misunderestimate me.

Comment: @Richard I think Bush was on to something when he invented that word that would live in infamy. I certainly did mistakenly underestimate the power to locate this in only an hour.  I’m still going to reread these, never got to any of “The Riftwar Legacy” books or beyond.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero - Magician was the best book in the series. Everything afterwards was a huge letdown. My advice is to pretend that there was only one book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the quote you're referring to :

> Kulgan fetched out his tabac pouch and handed it across to the dwarf [Dolgan]
>   “Providentially,” said Kulgan, “my pipe and pouch are two items always
>   kept upon my person at all times. I can withstand the loss of my other
>   goods—though the loss of my two books troubles me deeply—but to endure
>   any circumstance without the comfort of my pipe is unthinkable.”
>
> “Aye,” agreed the dwarf as he lit up his own, “you have the right of
>   it there. **Except for autumn’s ale-—and my loving wife’s company or a
>   good fight, of course—there’s little to match the pipe for pure
>   pleasure.”** He drew forth a long pull and blew out a large cloud of
>   smoke to emphasize his point.
>
> <sub><sup>[Magician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_%28novel%29) (Raymond E. Feist) - Chapter Nine : Mac Mordain Cadal</sup></sub>

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!